# How do I remove the Bitnami banner from joomla website on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am new to AWS and am struggling to find my way around their services. That being said I have a Joomla instance in a lightsail package. The site is ready to launch so I need to remove the Bitnami banner. The instructions seem very simple but I don't understand this line:
Log in to into your server console using SSH and execute the following command. Remember to replace APPNAME with the actual name or directory location of your application.
I'm logged in using SSH but can't figure out what they mean by the "actual name" or "directory location" of my application. Where is that listed? I used the name of my joomla instance, but got the response:

> /opt/bitnami/apps/Joomla-1/bnconfig: command not found

Can someone please help me with identifying the actual name or directory location of my application?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using the default path**

By default Joomla is setup in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/joomla` directory so you can simply run the following command

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/bnconfig --disable_banner 1
```

**If you have changed the default path**
If you have modified the joomla installation path on the server you will need to identify the installation folder.

If you login to your server via SSH perform the following:

- `ls -lah /opt/bitnami/apps` - Identify the folders in the apps directory(one of them will be for your joomla site)
- `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/$SUBFOLDER/bnconfig --disable_banner 1` - Run the command using the output of the subfolder from the previous command

Comment: That did it Chris. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem glad I could help